# How to parse the following JSON to retrieve the values

Tags: javascript, json

i have got the following JSON

```
[{
    "T1": "cost"
}, {
    "T6": "Service Tax"
}, {
    "T3": "VAT"
}, {
    "T4": "OtherTax2"
}, {
    "T5": "OtherTax1"
}, {
    "T2": "Discount"
}, {
    "T7": "Service Charge"
}];
```

and i am able to retrive T1 value using

```
var t1value = myjson[0].T1;
```

But when i am trying to retrive T2 value why its is giving me undefined

http://jsfiddle.net/mwv6r0df/4/

Could you please tell me how can i retrieve all the values

Comment: That's an array of objects. Each object has only 1 property. Come on, this is  pretty basic.

Comment: myjson[5].T2; "an array"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: To retrieve all the values just use a `for` loop.

Comment: As I see that is an array of objects and they have different properties. If there is no convention in property name, I think it's hard to retrieve all the values.

Answer (score 2):

That's because first `index` has no property name `T2`.

First `Index` has only one property name `T1`.

`5th` index has property name `T2`

```
console.log(myjson[5].T2);
```

If your object design is

```
[{
    "T1": "cost",
    "T6": "Service Tax",
    "T3": "VAT",
    "T4": "OtherTax2",
    "T5": "OtherTax1",
    "T2": "Discount",
    "T7": "Service Charge"
}];
```

Then your approach is correct.

```
console.log(myjson[0].T2);
```

But In your design every index has different property.

<kbd>**[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/mwv6r0df/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON

```
console.log(myjson.toString());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...,[object Object]
       ↑              ↑                ↑                   ↑
idx = (1)            (2)              (3)                 (n)
```

---

If way this

```
var myjson = 
[{
    "T1": "cost", 
    "T6": "Service Tax",
    "T3": "VAT",
    "T4": "OtherTax2",
    "T5": "OtherTax1",
    "T2": "Discount",
    "T7": "Service Charge"
}];
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[object Object]
```